# Dystopia where match-making computer gives user no choice

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, dystopia, love

I need help remembering the name of a story that had a computer that functioned as a vending machine for relationships, but where the user had little to no control over who came out.

> The main point was that people ended up being more satisfied with less
>  choice because it forced them to search for the good in each other
>  rather than having the privilege to be selective based on what we
>  don't like in others.

It's killing me that I can't remember.

Comment: Roughly speaking, when did you read this? Was it in a book, magazine, or something else? Do you remember any descriptions of characters? What language was it in? Even tiny details may help us find this.

Comment: It was in English, I've been reading Asimov, Philip K. Dick, and others from that era recently. The main character was a man. I think the computer had only one button.

Comment: So the man pushed a button, and one of the women came out of the machine?

Comment: This has a very faint resemblance to Brian Aldiss "The Primal Urge" inasfar as this has automated matchmaking, but as far as I remember people in the Aldiss novel were less than satisfied with the results.

Comment: @user14111 That's the idea. I think you could select if you wanted a man or woman to come out.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Took a quick look at The Primal Urge. It looks really interesting, but it's definitely too long. I believe it was fairly short, only a few pages.

Comment: Did you find it? If not, try clenching your left fist. Seriously, do it.

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like Matched by Allie Condie

Via Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched

> The novel is a dystopian YA novel about a tightly-controlled society in which young people are "matched" with their life partners at the age of 17. The main character is seventeen-year-old Cassia Reyes, who is Matched with her best friend, Xander Carrow. However, when viewing the information for her Match, the picture of another young man - Ky Markham, an acquaintance outcast at her school - is flashed across the screen. As Cassia attempts to figure out the source of the mishap, she finds herself conflicted about whether her Match is appropriate for her - and whether the Society is all that it seems to be.

Comment: The plot's similar, but Gruzzles said it was a very short short story (only a few pages). This is a novel, and the first in a trilogy no less.

Comment: Yeah, that's not it, but I appreciate the answer!